# Joomla module positions not working

Tags: css, joomla, joomla-module

I'm using Joomla, and as far as I can tell I have done everything right for my template, but can't get Module positions to work

I have the correct XML file setup I think and this is my HTML tag:

```
    <jdoc:include type="modules" name="topnav">
```

The page is X if you look at the page source it is rendering that tag - I would expect that to disappear, and to be replaced with the content I have told the Joomla backend to put there?

Very confused!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this-

```
<jdoc:include type="modules" name="topnav" />
```

You are missing closing tag.

let me know if this does not work.

Comment: This is correct. The regex to find the include tags is `#<jdoc:include\ type="([^"]+)" (.*)\/>#iU`. So a whitespace + closing slash is required.

Comment: This is correct also you should enable that module for corresponding menus.then only it will appear in the correct pages

Answer (score 0):

How are they not working? Are the positions updating in admin, but not on the website? Or are they not updating in the admin page too? From what I remember of Joomla, you have to click on the 'save' icon once you've rearranged all your positions.